# Problem with label and tick in tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, tkz-euclide

I have an old `.tex` file, which worked correctly before, now I'm having a problem with the following code,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmax=6,xmin=1]
            \tkzAxeX[label=$t$]
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output is,
[image: 1]

I would like t to replace only the x, not that it is on the line. I didn't change anything in the code, and before it worked, I don't know if the documentation has changed or what ....

My packages are all updated...

Comment: Other examples on this site also use `\tkzAxeX[label]` and if you compile them, the same error shows up. The examples in the `tkz-base` manual use `\tkzDrawX[label]` instead which seems to work properly. However, the manual refers to `label` as option for `\tkzAxeX`. Some changes seem to have been made.

Comment: Exactly, this is not the only problem in my document (which some time ago was working), I thought it could be something on my computer, but it must be a problem in the recent versions of the package.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `\tkzDrawX` and `\tkzLabelX` instead. So that you can customize your axis (and in many more ways, read the documentation for more).

[image: tkz-euclide t-axis]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmax=6,xmin=1]
            \tkzDrawX[label=$t$,text=blue,color=red]
            \tkzLabelX[text=blue,below = 3pt]
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The documentation (for tkz-base 3.06c, page 19) states that `label` is a valid option for `\tkzAxeX`. This should be corrected then, if this option does not yield proper results when used this way.

Comment: You're right. Maybe Alain Matthes would have a look at this specific point. I don't know if he still maintains this package. Last update is from 2020-04-06.

Comment: I have an old file (class notes), which was working perfectly, I decided to make some changes to the text and several graphics presented problems,I thought it could be something on my computer, but apparently newer versions of the package have problems...

Comment: This is totally possible. You could give feeback to Alain on CTAN, maybe.